# Core i7-2600 CPU Cooler

Tags: cooling, intel, heat-sink

I am upgrading an old Lenovo ThinkCentre I got cheap of eBay (a ThinkCentre M72e SFF - i3-2120, 4GB, 240GB) and I desperately need to speed it up - a new CPU should do it. I have an old i7-2600 lying around, but with no cooler. What cooler can I get for this CPU that will fit in my case? It must be powerful, because I frequently put this machine under load.

 - Must be air-cooled

 - Must fit in my SFF case an on my motherboard

 - It's cramped inside, and my GTX 1650 LP takes a bit of space, so it can't be intrusive around the CPU

 - For anyone who doesn't know, it has a socket LGA1155

Comment: There are still a lot of 115x coolers out there, it shouldn't be too hard to find a low profile from maybe Noctua that fits your socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be something that might work for you it's from Noctua, a little pricey but very low profile and efficient and should be more than enough for that cpu to keep it cool.

[Link](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/vbLwrH/noctua-nh-l9i-chromaxblack-3384-cfm-cpu-cooler-nh-l9i-chromaxblack)